# Will this PCI-E 1X to 16X Bottleneck my GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu, pci-express, adapter

I've got two GPUs, a GTX 1060 and a GTX 960. I'd like to use them in the same rig (not SLI or CrossFire, just on the same motherboard) for power rendering. The problem is, my current Motherboard only has 1 PCI-E X16 Slot, which my GTX 1060 occupies. I have 4 PCI-E X1 slots available. If I got [this adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008BZBGPO), would there be any bottlenecks? And if there is, how significant? I only plan on using the Second GPU for rendering with *Blender*, not gaming or anything. Also, if there is a bottleneck, what solution would you recommend? (Besides getting a new motherboard that has 2 X16's)

Comment: "If I got this adapter, would there be any bottlenecks?" - Yes;  "Also, if there is a bottleneck, what solution would you recommend? (Besides getting a new motherboard that has 2 X16's)" - You removed the only solution to avoid the bottleneck.

Comment: [A PCI Express 3.0 Video Card into a PCI-E 1.0 x16 slot](http://superuser.com/questions/427196/a-pci-express-3-0-video-card-into-a-pci-e-1-0-x16-slot)

Comment: [What are the performance differences between PCI-Express x16 and x4](http://superuser.com/questions/766789/what-are-the-performance-differences-between-pci-express-x16-and-x4?rq=1).  *Take a look at the difference between a GTX 670 on a PCI-E x4 lane vs PCI-E x16, the minimum FPS is about 50% lower.*  The differences with a GTX 960 will even be greater on a 1x lane.

Comment: @Ramhound I expected such in a gaming since, I'm still on the edge because I'm not sure how this will impact rendering images with Blender.

Comment: Your performance will be impacted.  You would have to benchmark just the GTX 960 on the PCI-E x16 vs the PCI-E x1 in order to determine how much of a performance drop there wil be.